# Cant display image in Laravel Running on Local Xampp

Tags: laravel, xampp, symlink

This is mine Symlink where the image has been stored but was not able to display the image

```php
 <img class="img-responsive thumbnail"
      src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('post/'.$post->image) }}" 
      alt="">
```

This is `.env` file code

```
APP_NAME=kanufha
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:{{Key}}
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

This is where image is stored:

```
RootDirectory > Storage > app > public > post > "name_of_file".extension
```

This throws `error 404`:

```
http://localhost/storage/post/testing-2018-10-04-5bb559f882db0.png
```

Comment: try storage_path('public/post/'.$post->image), That should give you the correct url. Strange it doesnt give you the correct url

Comment: Is the mime type for that file type configured on your server? I use IIS but I had a similar issue with .json files.

Comment: **no its .png**

Comment: how about http://localhost/public/storage/post/testing-2018-10-04-5bb559f882db0.png ?

Answer (score 4):

update your APP_URL in .env file with the correct path if you are using php artisan serve command than path will be http://localhost:8000

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking everywhere for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as your image's source: **{{url('storage/post/'.$post->image)}}**

instead of this: **{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('post/'.$post->image) }}**

Hope it will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and try again if the image working

Comment: I have run this command before thats how i am saving the imge Storage::disk(public)->put('post/'.$image->name);